# update current Date Time every time I change any other field in Django models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a situation wherein I have a model class with various variables of different data types along with a ForeignKey and I want to update DateTime every time a change is made to any one of the variables inside that class. The code is :

```
`class Career(models.Model):
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    job_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    functional_area = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    job_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    roles_responsibilitis = models.TextField(null=True)
    qualification = models.TextField(null=True)
    additional_info = models.TextField(null=True)
    perks = models.TextField(null=True)
    company_description = models.OneToOneField(General, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField('posted_date')`
```

I want to update 'posted_on' with the current DateTime after every update to any of this fields in the database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `auto_now`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

Comment: I'm a bit confused as I'm new to Django. Can you suggest me which one to use auto_now or auto_now_add? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: `auto_now` will update every time that object is saved using model.save(). `auto_now_add` is for when the object is created.

Comment: Thanks, @Hayden. Worked for me